# Can I Assign a variable in a SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am doing a SQL Insert to populate my table.  I have a unique generated ID in one table that I would like to use in another table for my join.  Is this possible?

.NET MVC --

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connections))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ContactInfo_Add", connect);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", name));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("address", address));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Product", name));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Quantity", address));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("DueDate", city));
    connect.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

SQL SERVER --

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Contact_Add]
@name varchar(40),
@address varchar(60),
@Product varchar(40),
@Quantity varchar(5),
@DueDate datetime
AS 
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO DBO.PERSON
     (Name, Address) VALUES (@name, @address)
     INSERT INTO DBO.PRODUCT_DATA
     (PersonID, Product, Quantity, DueDate) VALUES (@Product, @Quantity, @DueDate)
END
```

The code inserts fine.  Just how do I pull the Auto-generated PersonID to use in PRODUCT_DATA?

Comment: user54197 look at KM's answer and my comment on it. There are some potential issues with using Scope Identity to return the PersonID if someone unknowingly changes your Store Procedure.

Comment: @msarchet: Care to elaborate on what these potential issues are? Of course someone can break your stored procedure if they change it without knowing how it works, but that has nothing to do with `SCOPE_IDENTITY` itself - they're just as likely to break an `OUTPUT INSERTED` clause.

Comment: Exactly what you just said, it's not an issue with SCOPE_IDENTITY itself, that works great. There is just more certainty on using the output inserted since it won't break if someone changes the order of the stored procedure. It's not perfect as obviously someone could always break your SP, regardless of how you are returning a value. Using a parameter like `@variable int output` is the most obvious way to go for getting output. But still someone could break that, but that is still harder.

Comment: In all the time I've used SQL Server (good grief ten years now!), I have never seen anyone change a stored proc to get the wrong scope_identity. I suppose it could happen but generally I don't let anyone write procs who doesn't know what they are doing. 

However, if you have the newer versions of SQl Server the output clause is the better way to go for many reasons including you can return a value that is not generated through an identity or even more than one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the last inserted identity value:

```
DECLARE @PersonID INT

INSERT INTO dbo.Person (Name, Address)
VALUES (@Name, @Address)

SET @PersonID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.Product_Data (PersonID, Product, Quantity, DueDate)
VALUES (@PersonID, @Product, @Quantity, @DueDate)
```

Comment: you can have insert into both tables without using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and in a single INSERT statement, check out my answer for how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585723/can-i-assign-a-variable-in-a-sql-stored-procedure/2585918#2585918

Comment: @KM: I'm aware that you can do it with a single statement using an `OUTPUT INSERTED` clause. In general I find separate statements more readable/maintainable: one statement for each piece of work.

Answer (score 6):

**You don't need to use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), use OUTPUT and a single INSERT statement!**
this does require SQL Server 2005 and up

Try this:

setup the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (PersonID int identity(1,1), Name varchar(40), Address varchar(60))
CREATE TABLE Test2 (PersonID int, product varchar(40),Quantity varchar(5),DueDate datetime)
```

create the procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestSP
@name varchar(40),
@address varchar(60),
@Product varchar(40),
@Quantity varchar(5),
@DueDate datetime
AS 
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     INSERT INTO Test1
             (Name, Address)
             OUTPUT INSERTED.PersonID, @Product, @Quantity, @DueDate
             INTO Test2
         VALUES 
             (@name, @address)

END
```

test the code

```
exec TestSP 'name','address','product',123,'1/1/2010'
select * from Test1
select * from Test2
```

output

```
PersonID    Name                 Address
----------- -------------------- -----------------------
1           name                 address

(1 row(s) affected)

PersonID    product   Quantity DueDate
----------- --------- -------- -----------------------
1           product   123      2010-01-01 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Agreed using scope identity works until someone changes your stored procedure causing the last value returned to not be the correct one. Oops

Comment: this is an easy way to add items to a log table.  You can even have multiple OUTPUT statements at one time.  Also, if you remove the INTO it returns a result set.  for example put `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` between `INTO Test2` and `VALUES`.  when you run the procedure TestSP, it will insert into the two tables and return a result set containing the Test1 table (two `INSERT`s and a `SELECT` within one `INSERT`!).